# How to style mui switch track thumb checked and unchecked?

Tags: material-ui

I am trying to style my switch to have a certain color then disabled and certain color when enabled , my current code looks like this and I want to use makeStyles, the issue here is the track get orange color only then disabeld.

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
  // style class
  switch: { 
      "& .MuiSwitch-thumb": {
        backgroundColor: "orange",
      },
      "& .MuiSwitch-track": {
        backgroundColor: "orange",
      },
    },
  }))
  
  
 <Switch /*color="primary"*/ className={classes.switch} disabled={!oneRepMax} size="small" checked={check} onChange={handleSwitch} />
```

Comment: Can you add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It's nice that you've added a snippet, but it doesn't function currently. It seems there's a good bit of missing context that an MRE would address. Since you're using [`makeStyles`](https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/), I assume you're using MUI pre-v5. [Here's a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nz488) that you can use as a starting point to create an MRE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override the color of checked & unchecked switch with the help of `createTheme`. Four styles we need to override - **thumb** (checked & unchecked) & **track** (checked & unchecked) -

```
  const theme = createTheme({
    components: {
      MuiSwitch: {
        styleOverrides: {
          switchBase: {
            //thumb - unchecked
            color: "orange"
          },
          colorPrimary: {
            "&.Mui-checked": {
              // thumb - checked
              color: "red"
            }
          },
          track: {
            // track - unchecked
            opacity: 0.2,
            backgroundColor: "blue",
            ".Mui-checked.Mui-checked + &": {
              // track - checked
              opacity: 0.9,
              backgroundColor: "pink"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

[image: Edit customize Switch via theme]